Why do i get CORS error on a Keycloak redirect using a Quarkus backend and an Angular client?
I'm developing a simple Angular-Quarkus-Keycloak Authentication application. The application, once logged in with Keycloak, retrieves the access token, and then sends the access token to my Quarkus backend for validation.
The access token retrieval works as espected, using an Authorization Code Flow PKCE.
When i execute the get request with the Authentication: Bearer , i get this error:
Cors Error
I enabled CORS on my Quarkus backend as it follows:
application.properties file on Quarkus backend
The Quarkus Extensions used by my backend are:
Quarkus Backend Extensions
The HTTP request fired from Angular Client is:
Angular HTTP GET request
I'm using keycloak.js and keycloak.angular packages.
The resource i'm trying to access on the backend:
Quarkus Resource
The configuration on my Keycloak server:
Keycloak Server Configuration
I have no idea how to fix this.
I've tried changing Keycloak configurations lots of times, adding specific web origins or generic (*), but it's no use.
I've tried changing Quarkus configuration too, adding specific origins, but no use.

do not post pictures of code/errors - post as (formatted) text

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
